# css not updating after re-redering component in redux react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to create a webpage using React.
used redux for data access.

My problem is that when I click on any product, it shows me a perfect page, but if I go back and then again click on another product, my page shows me the data of the new product, but it does not change the photo height in CSS.

[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4qd7.png)

[product 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ2d5.jpg)[product 2(its doesnt changing first image height)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enh48.png)

```
export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { product: {} }, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
        return {
            loading: true,
            ...state     <------i am sending the previous state
        }
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            loading: false,
            product: action.payload,
        }
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
        return {
            loading: false,
            error: action.payload
        }
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
        return {
            ...state,
            error: null
        }

    default:
        return state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first iterate, and then provide the changes.

```js
        return {
            ...state     <------ iterate
            loading: true, <----- set new values
        }
```

In addition, you should always iterate, just to make sure, you're not changing the whole state.

```js
export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { product: {} }, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state
            loading: true,
        }
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            product: action.payload,
        }
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            error: action.payload
        }
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
        return {
            ...state,
            error: null
        }

    default:
        return state
}
```

Comment: its does not working

Comment: then most likely the problem is not in the reducer, but rather component or somewhere else. You should provide component as well.

Comment: @Idruskis here is my product details page, [link](https://pastebin.com/mhUJXJbH)